# How do I export my mongoose model on NPM?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

I want to export my mongoose model on NPM so that I could use it on another project.

Currently, I have two separate applications that will use the same mongoose model, and possibly both will run on two separate instances. One will be main application and another one will be the admin.

[image]

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  photo: { type: String, default: "http://placehold.it/350x150"},
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

So technically how would I export this to NPM so that I could it on my admin folder

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much publish [any folder that has a package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) as an npm module.

So to do this, you'd put whatever common code  you want to use in multiple projects into its own project folder.  I would also make it its own git repository to be able to version things as needed.  You'd also `npm init` that folder and manage its dependencies solo.

Then you'd run `npm publish` to push it to the public NPM repository.

That said, you don't have to do that.  To get the reuse you're looking for, another option is to just set it up as its own git repo, then use the git repo syntax in your consuming app's package.json files:

```
$ npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
```

Answer (score -1):

With this package [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) you can talk between applications with the help of the api's and update the User model if not exist in the Admin App.